# Yii2 multiple models in one form

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

How to use multiple models in one form in Yii2?

My case:
[image: ER diagram]

In my create action I can save into **agenda_fiscalizacao** table, but in update I receive this error when I try to load the form:

```
Call to a member function formName() on array
```

### My Update Action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $modelAgenda = AgendaFiscalizacao::findAll(['fiscalizacao_id' => $id]);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::loadMultiple($modelAgenda, Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $valid = $model->validate();
        $valid = $modelAgenda->validade() && $valid;

        if ($valid) {
            $model->save(false);
            $modelAgenda->save(false);
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelAgenda' => $modelAgenda
    ]);
}
```

## My form view

```
<?= $form->field($modelAgenda, 'agenda_id')->checkboxList(Agenda::combo(), ['class' => 'checkbox']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'bioma_id')->dropDownList(Bioma::combo(), ['prompt' => $prompt]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'nome')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'tipo_doc')->radioList(['CPF'=>'CPF', 'CNPJ'=>'CNPJ'], ['class' => 'radio']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'n_doc')->widget(MaskedInput::className(), ['mask' => ['999.999.999-99', '99.999.999/9999-99']]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'observacao')->textarea(['rows' => 7]) ?>
```

What could be wrong?

## EDIT (full error):

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**1)** If you mean working with multiple models of the same type, the error is in this line:

```
$valid = $modelAgenda->validade() && $valid;
```

First, it should be `$modelAgenda->validate()`, second `$modelAgenda` contains array of models, `validate()` method can be called only on single model.

For validating multiple models Yii2 suggests using built-in method `validateMultiple()`:

```
use yii\base\Model;

...

$valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelAgenda) && $valid;
```

Working with multiple models is well covered in official docs ([Collecting Tabular Input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html)).

Note that they recommend to index models array by `id` before like this:

```
$models = YourModel::find()->index('id')->all();
```

**2)** If you need just two models of different type, don't use `findAll()` because it's for finding multiple models and always returns array (even on empty result). Use `new` for `create` action and `findOne()` for `update` action to initialize models. Let's say you initialized two models, `$firstModel` and `$secondModel`, then you can load and save them like this:

```
$isSuccess = false;

Yii::$app->db->transaction(function () use ($isSuccess) {
    $areLoaded = $firstModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $secondModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post();
    $areSaved = $firstModel->save() && $secondModel->save();
    $isSuccess = $areLoaded && $areSaved;
});

if ($isSuccess) {
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

Transaction is added in case of saving of second model will fail (so the first model also will not be saved).

Alternatively, you can declare [transactions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#transactions%28%29-detail) inside your model, for example:

```
return [
    'admin' => self::OP_INSERT,
    'api' => self::OP_INSERT | self::OP_UPDATE | self::OP_DELETE,
    // the above is equivalent to the following:
    // 'api' => self::OP_ALL,
];
```

Then just use:

```
$firstModel->scenario = 'scenarioForTransaction';
$secondModel->scenario = 'scenarioForTransaction';
$areLoaded = $firstModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $secondModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post();
$areSaved = $firstModel->save() && $secondModel->save();

if ($areLoaded && $areSaved) {
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

For more than two models, it's better to use loops.

**P.S.** I'd recommend to separate saving to different controllers / actions and call it via AJAX, it will be more user friendly.

For saving relations read - [Saving Relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#saving-relations).

Comment: Doesn't work.
In my case the form doesn't load, so then does not even enter in IF.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @jflizandro I updated the answer with more detailed explanation.

Comment: I think the problem is in view, because when I comment the line that creates the checkboxList, the error disappears and the form is loaded correctly.

Comment: The checkboxList must receive the same model as the other fields ($form->field($model, 'agenda_id')->checkboxList...).

Answer (score 3):

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $modelAgenda = AgendaFiscalizacao::findAll(['fiscalizacao_id' => $id]);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelAgenda->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple([$model, $modelAgenda])) {

            $model->save(false);
            $modelAgenda->save(false);
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelAgenda' => $modelAgenda
    ]);
}
```

You can refer following link for example : http://blog.dedikisme.com/blog/2014/10/13/yii2-building-a-single-form-with-multiple-models

Answer (score 0):

You are not rendering $modelAgenda from view/update.php to view/_form.php file while using render in update file.